# Issue with the rendering of a navigation bar on Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue about the rendering of a navigation bar into Chrome browser.
There are a little space between each case of the navigation bar.

Here's an image illustrating this issue on Chrome :

[image]

I have not this problem with others browser like Firefox, Safari, Opera.

The navigation bar is structured as :

```
<div id="nav_bar">
                  <table class="linkcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/" class="main_link">Home</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/aphosisus/"
                             class="main_link">Aphosisus</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/sciences/"
                             class="main_link">Sciences</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/pposis/"
                             class="main_link">Pposis</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/lougdj/" class="main_link">Lougdj</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="navigation">
                          <a href="/cv" class="main_link">Cv</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

The navigation bar CSS is :

```
#nav_bar {
    background-image: url("./header_bg_min.jpg");
    border: 0px none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 798px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Could someone test this problem of rendering with its Chrome browser ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE :**

Thanks for your remarks, I forgot to say that this problem only appears with Chrome on MacOS Mavericks, I have tested with Chrome on Win7 and Linux and no problem with them.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the results in Chrome (47.0.2526.106). It could be possible that the white space is causing it. I know that if it is a list that if there is any space between list items this causing a small space in between the items. All I can say is try removing all white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your version of chrome is ignoring your inline style attributes. `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`
Try adding this css:

```
table.linkcontainer {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I also noticed in your CSS, div.navigation has padding:Opx, as in the letter O.